# Restricted about what the elses who's people can edit with ? On protected of sheet and range by protected sheets option

Tags: google-sheets, permissions, spreadsheet, user-permissions, restriction

I was setting that about protected sheets on my sheet is turning it on. With the specific setting those are :

1. Restricted by just only me (owner) can edit the whole sheets and range.
2. Anyone doesn't allowed or haven't a permission to edit **anything except a range I desired to allowed to people to edit.**

*But the problem is* :
When I'm trying to become anyone (who doesn't have that permission) and open it  on my g.sheet mobile was get on an update before it but point is. It just open ans work by once only every single I open it everytime. That's always happend when after I made a single changes with the ranges which is have an allowed ranges.

Comment: I have tried creating a Google Sheet with specific restrictions and shared it with another account on my phone. It worked normally and I did not notice anything strange. I could still write on ranges with access while I could not write on ranges without access on my phone. Can you please explain further what issue you have encountered so that we may try and replicate the issue on our side? It would be better if you could add screenshots so that we may further understand the issue.

Comment: Yes @PatrickdC It should be not just only a picture in maybe but It could be a video recording or macro recording and capture them or convert into a gif files which's whould make it this question are more clear it's because it getting realated to tracking action.

Comment: But I don't know how to make it happend (a gif files) ...

Comment: If you do not know how to record/create .gif files, posting multiple screenshots might work as well as it may shed some clues to the issues that you are experiencing.

Comment: I think I make a mistaken because it was twisted about  something to not supossed be done. What I've just do to resolved this is twisted it back to supossed be. It's about I've given a granted of an access for a special people (add an user as editor) for an particular ranges meanwhile it supossed be not happend. And has a given access as a viewer in a share and manage option. What is the right way for supposed be happend is make a twist of those both of setting what I've just done an above I've mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was did a mistaken because it was twisted about something what just did supossed be I'm not do. What I've just do to resolved this is just make them twisted it back to supossed be happend. It's about I've given a granted of an access for a special people (add an user as editor) for an particular ranges meanwhile it supossed be not happend to me to do that. And the other changes has an given access to that user as a viewer in a shared and manage option. What is the right way for supposed be happend is make them a twistedd back of those of both setting what I've just done an above I've mention it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).